# Making csv2latex work with OSX El Capitan and TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, editors, csv, scripts

I have encountered several difficulties making csv2latex work after excel2latex mysteriously failed after having worked fine for 2 years (no upgrades of office or anything)...

I am using TexMaker as my editor and when I try to run the csv2latex script from the folder I downloaded the editor shows me the .scpt-file as non-executable...

When I try to run the installer it tells me that Ruby is not installed, which it is. I checked in the Terminal using

`ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding the exact error output.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the installer script probably due to changes in the OS over time. Unfortunately without receiving bug reports, it's difficult to find out about them. (I am the author.)

You should be able to install the scripts manually:

### Installing the script

Copy `csv2latex` to `/usr/local/bin`. You will need to use `sudo` to do this.  From the folder of the package:

```
sudo cp csv2latex /usr/local/bin
```

The script itself needs to be installed into the TeXMaker scripts folder. (It doesn't go in `/usr/local/bin`.  To do this, you should open TeXMaker and then from the Scripts menu, choose "Open texmaker scripts folder". Copy or move the `csv2latex.scpt` file there. You should copy the one in the main folder of the downloaded files, not the copy from the `source` folder.

[image: scripts menu]

### Using the script

Select a range of cells from your spreadsheet application and copy them. Then choose the `csv2latex` script from the Scripts menu inside TeXMaker.

Choose the appropriate tabular format to format the cells with and click Ok.

You will then need to manually paste the cells into your document. (For reasons I don't understand, TeXMaker doesn't execute the script completely.)

Please note that `csv2latex` doesn't preserve Excel formatting or complex Excel tables, it simply is a way to quickly paste cells.

Answer (score 0):

Download `csv2latex` and unzip it. Locate two files under `source` called `csv2latex.scpt` and `csv2latex.scpt`. Move them to `/usr/local/bin`.
That is,

```
$ cd to/directory/of/source
$ mv csv2latex /usr/local/bin
$ mv csv2latex.scpt /usr/local/bin
```

in a terminal window.

Comment: This is incorrect. The `csv2latex.scpt` needs to be placed in the Scripts folder for TeXMaker.